# How can I increase the number of licensed runs when inventing Tech II items?

Tags: eve-online

I have recently started out with inventing Tech II variants of the various blueprints I have. I started with something nice and small so started creating Hobgoblin II blueprints. So far I have successfully created two Tech II blueprints and each of these have had a single licensed run on them.

The blueprint copies I have been inventing from have a number of licensed runs of 5 - does this influence the number of licensed runs the invented blueprint will have?

How can I increase the number of licensed runs when inventing Tech II items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to achieve this, is to use decryptors.
However, they can be pretty costly and have also drawbacks. [War Strategon is for example roundabout 12 Million on the market](http://eve-central.com/home/quicklook.html?typeid=23182) at the time of writing.

Here is a list of available decryptors:

[image: Table of Items]

[Source](http://eve.wikia.com/wiki/Invention#Decryptors)

Notice how they can also decrease or increase other properties of the invention process such as chance or resulting ME/PE etc.

Personally I definitely advise against using them for cheap Items like Drones. I only use decryptors when inventing ships.

Another thing useful to know for later is that Freighter and Jump Freigter have a run limit of 1 licensed production run. So those decryptors do nothing when it comes to the runs. Always check the blueprint of the resulting item via the auto link system in the chat what the maximum of licensed runs of that item is.